# Adjusting the width of the column with the dates in moderncv

Tags: pdftex, moderncv

I'm trying to adjust the width of the column with the dates in the cventry item, in order to have all the text justified at the same level.

You can see in the attached image what is my issue with the width of the columns.
[image]

I have tried to add this options without success:

```
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}
```

Comment: Not without seeing your full code that produced the posted image.

Comment: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv